# How Can we use Laravel Custom helper in specific controller?

Tags: php, laravel

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

it was not calling on specific controller
is it necessary to autload helper?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Do you custom helpers reside inside a class or a custom function loaded via composer.json?

Answer (score 1):

First create a Helpers.php file anywhere in your project directory, mostly laravel folks create helper file in **App** directory (App/Helpers.php).

Then in your composer.json file, in **'autoload'** option add that file like this.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers.php"
        ]
    }
```

Now any function or variable define in that Helper.php file will be globally accessible.

Comment: it is necessary to autoload globally? and is this possible to use helper file in some of my specific views

Comment: yes it is necessary, and yes you can use helper file in your views.